# Undefined Variable : Claim

Tags: cakephp-2.3

This is my Controller code

```
<?php
public function view(){
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->loadModel('Claim');
        $this->Claim->unbindModel(
            array('belongsTo' => array('User',"Category"),
                'hasMany' => array('Response')));
        $user= $this->User->findById($this->params['id']);
        $claim=$this->Claim->find('all', array(
                        'conditions' => array('user_id' => $user['User']['id']),
                        'fields' => array('title','id','support_count','oppose_count','description','category_id')));

        if(isset($user['User'])):
        $this->set('User',$user);
        else:
        $this->Session->setFlash('User Not Found!', 'flash',array('alert'=>'error'));
        $this->redirect('/');
        endif;

    }?>
```

And This is my model code

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    public $validate = array(
        'handle' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'Invalid Username'
            ),
            'between' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 5, 15),
                'message' => 'Username should be between 5 to 15 characters'
            )),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 5, 15),
            'message' => 'Password should be between 5 to 15 characters',
            'last' => true,
            'required' => true
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'Enter valid email address'
            )
        )
    ); }
```

And This is View code

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($Claim['Claim']['title'], 
            array('Controller'=>'User','action'=>'view')); ?>
```

I am getting this error "Undefined variable: Claim [APP/View/User/view.ctp, line 6]"
I tried to define "claim" in model as public $name = 'Claim'; but it didn't work den i tried to define it as $this->set($claim('Claim')); but still i am getting same error...I need some help,can anyone help me with this please

Comment: you haven't set the variable `$Claim` in the view, with `$this->set('Claim', $claim)` (or similar) in the controller

Comment: i Wrote  <?php foreach ($claim as $Claim) ?> in view and $this->set('Claim',$claim); in controller but it didn't work so i removed it

Comment: well, you need to decide where you stand with the uppercase, if you set `$this->set('Claim',$claim)`, you can't call `$claim` (lowercase) in the view, you'll have it available in `$claim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Nunser said, you need to set the variable $Claim in the view, using $this->set('Claim', $claim) in your controller. The Model fetches data from a database. Then passes it on to a Controller where you can access it via $this->MODELNAME->METHOD. Here the data is processed. Eventually the Controller (not the Model) passes it on to the view. So you need to set it in the Controller.

Additionally: if you would be following CakePHP conventions (and really, it's all about conventions) you wouldn't need to use loadModel in line 3 and 4. Maybe have a look at CakePHP relations too.
Have a look at this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html for a short MVC explanation in Cake, and this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html for an introduction to relations.

Comment: If i remove loadModel, it shows me error, call to member function find() on non-object

Comment: Like I said: follow the CakePHP conventions and name your files correctly. A "s" can make a huge difference. Also better link your models together instead of loading them manually.

Comment: Thank you guys , I have found the solution thanks "pudelhund" and     "Nunser"